# Converting Keys and Values of the same length into Dictionary form

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a function with two arguments:

- keys (i.e. `['a','b','c']`)
- values to be put into a dictionary (i.e. `[1,2,3]`)

and if the lists are the same length, I put them in dictionary form and return the dictionary. Otherwise, I return the keyword `None` from the function.

```py
def dict_build(keys,values):
    keys = ['']
    values = []
    dictionary = dict(zip(keys, values))
    if len(keys) == len(values):
        return dictionary
    else:
        return None

print(dict_build(['a','b','c'],[1,2,3])== { 'a': 1,'b': 2,'c': 3 })
# False
```

The output here should be `True` as the lists have the same length. Where am I going wrong here?

Comment: See this [lovely debugging site](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for help.  One or two simple `print` commands to check your variable values, will quickly show your problem.

Comment: Also, since you are testing the len(keys) == len(values) regardless of what is placed in the dictionary, you will always return the result of this test.  Your function doesn't need to perform the zip operation unless you want to return the dictionary (i.e. key length = value length)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function immediately overwrites the `keys` and `values` parameters with empty lists, so you always return an empty dictionary.

Just deleting the first two lines of the function should fix it.  You could also shorten it down further to just:

```
def dict_build(keys,values):
    if len(keys) == len(values):
        return dict(zip(keys, values))
    else:
        return None
```